# $ git clone http://mySite.com/dirWhereTheRepoIs, how can I clone a repo through http?

Tags: git

**Creating Trial .git -repo**

```
$ mkdir Test; cd Test; git init
$ echo "Just dummy test file" > test1; git add .
$ git commit -m "cloning soon through http, this repo is in public_html -dir" 
$ pwd
/users/hhh/public_html
```

**And now trying to clone it**

```
$ git clone http://mysite.com/hhh/Test/
Cloning into Test...
fatal: http://mysite.com/hhh/Test/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
$ git update-server-info
$ git clone http://mysite.com/hhh/Test/
Cloning into Test...
fatal: http://mysite.com/hhh/Test/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

How can I clone the repo like that?

Comment: are you running `git update-server-info` from the server? it's not clear from your description

Comment: @DorShemer: yes I am running the command in the server where I have the repo, the repo is in the public_html -dir from which I am trying to clone it.

Comment: Does `http://mysite.com/` properly resolve from the host itself?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://kasunh.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/git-over-https/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup and use SmartHTTP - http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html

SmartHTTP is the standard now.